# HDF5 write to a single file from two communicators

Tags: mpi, hdf5

I've encountered a problem that when I write to a single file to different groups with 2 MPI ranks, I get only one of the groups' data.

My pseudo code:

### MPI

```
plist = define_property_list()
fid = h5fopen(file, access, plist)
gid = h5gopen(fid)
did = h5dcreate(gid)
h5dwrite(did)
close_everything()
```

When above is executed with two MPI ranks, I only get one group's data.

Does anyone know what could be the cause?

thanks

Comment: are you using parallel hdf5?

Comment: yes, im using parallel hdf5